# Making Active Cell More Apparent Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sometimes the default green border that Excel uses to highlight the active cell is too hard for me to see, especially when there is a sea of data.

Is there a way to adjust the width or color of the border for the active cell or
auto-highlight it? Is there a way to do this without macros?

Answer (score 1):

By default the active cell *(B9)*  is like:

[image]

If you open Excel Options and clear the Show Gridlines checkbox:

[image]

The active cell will better stand out:

[image]

Comment: Fair enough, but the active cell border will still not show well in tables with borders. Ideally, I want the active cell highlighted.

Comment: @GTyler  This is about the best we can do....without VBA

Answer (score 1):

This may be OK for occasional times when you need to locate the active cell on the screen. Point to one of the cell styles (e.g. Bad) in the Style Group on the Home tab. You can click the style to temporarily apply the style to the cell, then CTRL+Z to undo it. Unfortunately you have to do this after a cell has been selected so it's not efficient if you need to do it many times.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the gridlines, you can make them light gray. That retains the grid but makes the active ell border much easier to see. From the File menu, select Options, then Advanced. Scroll down to Display options for this worksheet. Select the Gridline color selector and select the lightest gray color.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good work around, I remove the boarders, do my searching, the close the workbook without saving so I don't mess up the sheet.  It's a shame Microsoft didn't put more effort into making the default highlight better (or customizable)!

Comment: It's a shame Micro$oft didn't put in more effort period. Marketing, (and locking in the market (and stealing the market)) has been their core business from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a very busy spreadsheet that I have problems seeing the active cell.  I find that either switching to the "Page Break Preview" to see where I am at the moment helps or sometimes simply scolling to reduce the size for a moment helps.